# How to add permission pop up to access camera in simulator (ios) flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, permissions, camera, qr-code

I am using `qr_flutter` package and trying in iphone simulator, but I get an error that say `CameraException (CameraException(cameraPermission, Permission denied to access the camera))` I have been using `permission_handler:^4.4.0+hotfix.2` package to check the permission to access the camera, here is the code:

```
cameraPermission() async {
    PermissionStatus permission =
        await PermissionHandler().checkPermissionStatus(PermissionGroup.camera);
    print(permission);
    print("kk");
  }
```

and the result is `permission granted`. Is there something else that I need to add more, so that pop up permission to access camera will show up?

Comment: You can't access camera using simulator. Please debug with a real device.

Comment: @HasilT I had been using image.picker in my another project and test it in simulator, then pop up to ask permission access camera shows up..after I click "ok" another pop up shows that say: camera is unavailable (in simulator)... same like that case, can I at least show the pop up permission to access camera ?